# Floating and width 100%

Tags: css, webkit, css-float, html

I've written this code:

```
<body>
<div>
    <div style="padding:10px;float:left;height:500px;background-color:#ff6a00;">
        Div1 -> Floated
    </div>
    <div style="padding:10px;height:600px;background-color:#5c64bb;display:-webkit-flex">
        Div2 -> Not Floated
    </div>
</div>
```

And result is the below image, I could achieve this result with using -webkit-flex display which works just in chrome, is there any idea which can give me the same result.

By the way, I don't want to use margin-left for Div2 and position absolute either.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind specifying a static width for your left side you can achieve the flex type layout for the right with this:

```
<div style="display:table;width:100%;">
    <div style="display:table-cell;width:130px;vertical-align:top;">
        <div style="padding:10px;height:500px;background-color:#ff6a00;">
            Div1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:top;">
        <div style="padding:10px;height:600px;background-color:#5c64bb;">
            Div2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LHZKp/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a similar effect using `display: inline-block;` on the second div and percentage widths.

```
<div>
    <div style="padding:10px;float:left;height:500px;background-color:#ff6a00;width:15%;">
        Div1 -> Floated
    </div>
    <div style="padding:10px;height:600px;width: 80%;background-color:#5c64bb;display:inline-block;">
        Div2 -> Not Floated
    </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wUhKR/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) but as you see in title I wanna set **width:100%** for Div2, There is a way with **display: block** and **margin-left** as many as Div1 width.